# laravel withsum with additional where clause

Tags: laravel

I know you can do a `withSum` on a relationship like this:

```php
$posts = Post::withSum('comments', 'votes')->get();
```

But I like to chain an additional where clause on this, something like this (doesn't work but as an example):

```php
$posts = Post::withSum('comments', 'votes', function (Builder $query) {
                $query->where('comments.votes', '>', 5);
            })->get()
```

Is that possible?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ that works, feel free to add it as an answer!

Answer (score 3):

While [Aggregating Related Models](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#aggregating-related-models) is not explicit about this in the documentation, it does give us a clue by mentioning:

> If you need to set additional query constraints on the count query, you may pass an array keyed by the relationships you wish to count. The array values should be closures which receive the query builder instance.

> If you need to set additional query constraints on the count query, you can pass an encoded array by the relationships you want to count. The values in the array must be anonymous functions that receive the query builder instance.

So, we can take advantage of that anonymous function to modify the query builder instance so that instead of taking the default values (which would use the aggregate 'count'), and pass it the subquery we want to do, which is the where clause and the 'sum' of the column.

Said that, your query cuold looks like:

```
Post::withCount(['comments as comments_sum_votes' => function($query) {
    $query->where('comments.votes', '>', 5)->select(DB::raw('sum(votes)'));
}])->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, like so:

```php
$posts = Post::withSum([
   'comments' => fn ($q) => $q->where('votes', '>', 5)
], 'votes')->get();
```